# Unable to find a suitable output format while cutting video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using below command to cut video-

```
String complexCommand = new String[]{"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-c", "copy", filePath};
```

I got below error -

> "ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers\n
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/file3gpp.3gpp':\n  Metadata:\n
>   major_brand     : 3gp4\n    minor_version   : 0\n
>   compatible_brands: isom3gp4\n    creation_time   : 2018-04-09
>   12:04:29\n    com.android.version: 7.1.1\n  Duration: 00:00:04.88,
>   start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1425 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac
>   (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)\n
>   Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2018-04-09 12:04:29\n
>   handler_name    : SoundHandle\n[NULL @ 0xf622a600] Unable to find a
>   suitable output format for
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/cut_video.3gpp'\n/storage/emulated/0/Movies/cut_video.3gpp:
>   Invalid argument\n"

Why am i getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Recognized extension is `.3gp`. For custom extension, add `"-f", "3gp",` before `filePath`.